# enroll member request fails with signature verification

Tags: go, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

when I tried to enroll the "admin" user, the second call to CreateCertificatePair failed with the "Signature verification failed" message. BTW, I copied the enrollUser function from the eca_test.go. And those tests under membersrvc/ca package can be passed.

```
//Phase 2 of the protocol
spi := ecies.NewSPI()
eciesKey, err := spi.NewPrivateKey(nil, encPriv)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

ecies, err := spi.NewAsymmetricCipherFromPublicKey(eciesKey)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

out, err := ecies.Process(resp.Tok.Tok)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

req.Tok.Tok = out
req.Sig = nil

hash := primitives.NewHash()
raw, _ := proto.Marshal(req)
hash.Write(raw)

r, s, err := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, signPriv, hash.Sum(nil))
if err != nil {
    return err
}
R, _ := r.MarshalText()
S, _ := s.MarshalText()
req.Sig = &pb.Signature{Type: pb.CryptoType_ECDSA, R: R, S: S}

resp, err = ecapCient.CreateCertificatePair(context.Background(), req)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sergey mentioned, `CreateCertificatePair` requests the creation of a new certificate pair,
and according to the documentation,

During registration, the application sends a request to the certificate authority to verify the user registration and if successful, the CA responds with the user certificates and keys.

**Upon successful user authentication, the application will perform user registration with the CA exactly once. If registration is attempted a second time for the same user, an error will result.** 
This is the reason why the second call to `CreateCertificatePair` is failing. 
If you really want to register a user who has already been registered previously, you need to remove the temporary files ( the client enrollment certificate, enrollment key, transaction certificate chain, etc.) that were created by the CA server process, and to do that, run the following command,

```
rm -rf /var/hyperledger/production
```

`/var/hyperledger/production` is the directory where the certificates received from CA are stored.

Souce: [Note on security functionality](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#note-on-security-functionality)

Comment: well... the enrollUser function in the "eca_test.go" file, which do calls CreateCertificatePair twice. In addition, the official api docs also mention that "The CreateCertificatePair function allows a user to create and read their enrollment certificate pair. For this, the user has to do two successive invocations of this function. "  http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/MemberServicesAPI/

Comment: Just keep in mind that "rm -rf /var/hyperledger/production" will remove everything including ledger with all blocks in addition to certificates and keys...

Comment: Thanks Sergey for that. 
the certificates however are located in the subdirectory `/var/hyperledger/production/crypto/client/` you can remove it instead if you want to keep your ledger and blocks.

Comment: you would still only be able to enroll once.

Answer (score 0):

CreateCertificatePair requests the creation of a new enrolment certificate pair by the ECA.
"enrolment" certificate is unique and can be created just once per user by ECA

Second call to `CreateCertificatePair` for the same user will lead to error.

Comment: I don't think so. The official api docs say: "The CreateCertificatePair function allows a user to create and read their enrollment certificate pair. For this, the user has to do two successive invocations of this function."  pls check  http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/MemberServicesAPI/

Comment: Next phrase from the same document - "Firstly, both the signature and encryption public keys have to be handed to the ECA together with the one-time password previously returned by the RegisterUser function invocation." the one-time password cannot be used again in second login attempt.

Comment: actually, the second call used a new token.    out, err :=ecies.Process(resp.Tok.Tok)
req.Tok.Tok = out

Comment: besides, if I use the one-time password twice, the message will be "identity or token not match"